# Keyboard locale - key to string

Tags: java, input, keyboard, locale

I am retrieving key presses through the lwjgl 3 binding of GLFW. I would like to convert these to a character that I can then display on the screen using the operating systems current keyboard locale, or by picking the locale myself. Is there a way to achieve this with java + lwjgl? If not, which other library or general solution would you recommend?

Comment: I don't know about setting any locale, but the documentation seems to indicate unicode text support is available in glfw, so it would be a question of finding the LWJGL wrapper way of invoking it: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input.html#input_char

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank Google, not me. I just googled "lwjgl glfw input unicode" and boom - instant info.

Comment: I guess :P I was looking for a solution on google for the past hour, but didn't think of a direct unicode input instead of the translation of keycode to character.